# The best circle fitting algorithm

Tags: image-processing, geometry, computer-vision

I need a very precise algorithm for fitting a circle to the set of data points (actually I need to determine the center). The data comes after the binarization and segmentation of the image. 
I tried simple center of mass and  weighted center of mass algorithms and also pre-made OpenCv::fitEllipse function. I have obtained the best results from OpenCV function, but still, the accuracy is not sufficient. The results are impaired significantly, when the center is anchored in subpixel regions. 
The accuracy I obtained is not sufficient even when dealing with the modeled data, which is bad, as eventually, the procedure will have to deal with the data captured by comeras. 
Have you got any suggestions what kind of algorithm should I look for or have you got any ready solution? I would rather refrain from linking any external libs.
Thanks for your help.
[image]

edited:
Calibration target can be localizaed in any region of the field of view. Hereunder the best results I acieved with OpenCV procedure:

```
169,367 748,345  
167,557 820,788  
165,690 893,158  
164,047 965,197  
162,715 1036,729  
161,575 1108,089  
160,477 1179,552  
233,297 1015,313  
232,076 1086,965  
220,359 1229,578  
268,494 1160,275  
339,544 1162,980  
362,017 1235,669  
433,390 1238,491  
482,754 1168,299  
505,233 1241,039  
554,856 1170,664  
577,302 1243,439  
627,331 1172,795  
649,507 1245,665  
713,572 588,896  
711,995 661,853  
710,440 735,034  
708,722 808,856  
707,018 882,674  
705,377 956,169  
703,609 1029,211  
701,716 1101,950  
699,760 1174,689  
721,895 1247,620  
785,829 614,754  
784,344 687,750  
782,819 761,315  
781,292 835,225  
779,389 908,975  
777,619 982,335  
775,688 1055,275  
773,672 1128,091  
771,603 1200,724
```

Editted: The numerically generated model and the real coordinates of the centres:
[image]

```
51,1    79,8
51,1    179,8
51,1    279,8
51,1    379,8
51,1    479,8
51,1    579,8
51,1    679,8
51,1    779,8
51,1    879,8
51,1    979,8
51,1    1079,8
51,1    1179,8
51,1    1279,8
51,1    1379,8
51,1    1479,8
151,1   79,8
151,1   179,8
151,1   279,8
151,1   379,8
151,1   479,8
151,1   579,8
151,1   679,8
151,1   779,8
151,1   879,8
151,1   979,8
151,1   1079,8
151,1   1179,8
151,1   1279,8
151,1   1379,8
151,1   1479,8
251,1   79,8
251,1   179,8
251,1   279,8
251,1   379,8
251,1   479,8
251,1   579,8
251,1   679,8
251,1   779,8
251,1   879,8
251,1   979,8
251,1   1079,8
251,1   1179,8
251,1   1279,8
251,1   1379,8
251,1   1479,8
351,1   79,8
351,1   179,8
351,1   279,8
351,1   379,8
351,1   479,8
351,1   579,8
351,1   679,8
351,1   779,8
351,1   879,8
351,1   979,8
351,1   1079,8
351,1   1179,8
351,1   1279,8
351,1   1379,8
351,1   1479,8
451,1   79,8
451,1   179,8
451,1   279,8
451,1   379,8
451,1   479,8
451,1   579,8
451,1   679,8
451,1   779,8
451,1   879,8
451,1   979,8
451,1   1079,8
451,1   1179,8
451,1   1279,8
451,1   1379,8
451,1   1479,8
551,1   79,8
551,1   179,8
551,1   279,8
551,1   379,8
551,1   479,8
551,1   579,8
551,1   679,8
551,1   779,8
551,1   879,8
551,1   979,8
551,1   1079,8
551,1   1179,8
551,1   1279,8
551,1   1379,8
551,1   1479,8
651,1   79,8
651,1   179,8
651,1   279,8
651,1   379,8
651,1   479,8
651,1   579,8
651,1   679,8
651,1   779,8
651,1   879,8
651,1   979,8
651,1   1079,8
651,1   1179,8
651,1   1279,8
651,1   1379,8
651,1   1479,8
751,1   79,8
751,1   179,8
751,1   279,8
751,1   379,8
751,1   479,8
751,1   579,8
751,1   679,8
751,1   779,8
751,1   879,8
751,1   979,8
751,1   1079,8
751,1   1179,8
751,1   1279,8
751,1   1379,8
751,1   1479,8
851,1   79,8
851,1   179,8
851,1   279,8
851,1   379,8
851,1   479,8
851,1   579,8
851,1   679,8
851,1   779,8
851,1   879,8
851,1   979,8
851,1   1079,8
851,1   1179,8
851,1   1279,8
851,1   1379,8
851,1   1479,8
951,1   79,8
951,1   179,8
951,1   279,8
951,1   379,8
951,1   479,8
951,1   579,8
951,1   679,8
951,1   779,8
951,1   879,8
951,1   979,8
951,1   1079,8
951,1   1179,8
951,1   1279,8
951,1   1379,8
951,1   1479,8
1051,1  79,8
1051,1  179,8
1051,1  279,8
1051,1  379,8
1051,1  479,8
1051,1  579,8
1051,1  679,8
1051,1  779,8
1051,1  879,8
1051,1  979,8
1051,1  1079,8
1051,1  1179,8
1051,1  1279,8
1051,1  1379,8
1051,1  1479,8
1151,1  79,8
1151,1  179,8
1151,1  279,8
1151,1  379,8
1151,1  479,8
1151,1  579,8
1151,1  679,8
1151,1  779,8
1151,1  879,8
1151,1  979,8
1151,1  1079,8
1151,1  1179,8
1151,1  1279,8
1151,1  1379,8
1151,1  1479,8
```

Comment: Please provide a sample image of what circles you are trying to match. Also an image with mismatched circle would help to understand what's the problem.

Comment: Please post the expected center positions for your sample image to compare results.

Comment: Well, I meant that image I have already posted contains "egg shapes". Maybe I just exaggerated the problem, that camera can not see circles as ideal circles. I will post an image of the model with well known centres positions in a few minutes to test your procedure.

Comment: +1 for the trippy dots image! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### An Algorithm using Image Transformations and Clustering

---

I made up a small Algorithm using Image Transformations and some Statistic to detect your circles. Let's see if it is up to your error expectation.
Any good image and statistics library will do, I implemented it using Mathematica.

Run as follows:

**1. Import your image and run a Bottom Hat Transform**

We start trying to isolate the circles. The [Bottom Hat Transform](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.78.1116&rep=rep1&type=pdf) with a Box Matrix kernel helps. Almost any image library comes with the algorithm already implemented.

```
a = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiSjj.png";   
b = BottomHatTransform[Binarize@a, BoxMatrix[30]]
```

The result is

[image]

**2. Run a Hit Miss Transform to isolate the circles**

[The Hit Miss Transform](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitmiss.htm) excels in finding well defined geometrical objects. It is also easy to program and is almost always present in image libraries.

```
c = Binarize@HitMissTransform[b, DiskMatrix[20]]
```

The result is:

[image]

And our circles are already isolated and reduced to their central core.

**3. Get just the white pixels from image**

This is an implementation-dependent step, so I'll not comment on this one.

```
ttflat = Flatten[Table[{i, j, ImageData[c][[i, j]]}, {i, 1232}, {j, 1624}], 1];  
ttfilter = Select[ttflat, #[[3]] == 1 &];
```

Let's see how many pixels are left

```
Dimensions@ttfilter  
{3684, 3}
```

So 3684 pixels left, almost 82 per circle. Enough to do some statistics.

**3. Use Cluster Analysis to pick each circle**

Cluster Analysis may be an overkill here, but as I have it already implemented, is easier to use it than program something new :). You may do your own or use a stats library.

```
ttc = FindClusters[ttfilter, 45, Method -> {"Agglomerate", "Linkage" -> "Complete"}];
```

With our clusters already found, let's find the mean for x and y in each cluster. Those are the centers of the circles:

```
means = N[Mean /@ ttc, 5]
```

The result is a list of 45 coordinates like:

```
{{161.67, 1180.1}, {162.75, 1108.9}, 
 {164.11, 1037.6}, {165.47, 966.19} .....
```

We are almost done.

Let's check our result. We superimposed both images, drawing crosses and circles around the detected centers.

[image]

[**Click to enlarge**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suhBy.gif), so you may get an idea of the errors involved.

HTH!

**Edit**

I compared the results from your table with my results.

Assumming the circles are in straight lines, I used Least Squares Fit to trace a line and calculated the residuals.

Form the graph below, you may see that "M"y line fit better than "Y"ours. But that is assuming the circles aligned ...

[image]

**Edit 2**

These are the calculated coordinates for the first 45 circles in your second image. I have a systematic offset of 1 pixel. Probably due to some image manipulation I did, but is easy to correct :)  ... just subtracted one pixel on X and Y ...

```
{{51.135, 79.692}, {51.135, 179.69}, {51.135, 279.69},{51.135, 379.69}, {51.135, 479.69},
 {51.135, 579.69}, {51.135, 679.69}, {51.135, 779.69},{51.135, 879.69}, {51.135, 979.69}, 
 {51.135, 1079.7}, {51.135, 1179.7}, {51.135, 1279.7},{51.135, 1379.7}, {51.135, 1479.7}, 
 {151.13, 79.692}, {151.13, 179.69}, {151.13, 279.69},{151.13, 379.69}, {151.13, 479.69},
 {151.13, 579.69}, {151.13, 679.69}, {151.13, 779.69},{151.13, 879.69}, {151.13, 979.69}, 
 {151.13, 1079.7}, {151.13, 1179.7}, {151.13, 1279.7},{151.13, 1379.7}, {151.13, 1479.7}, 
 {251.13, 79.692}, {251.13, 179.69}, {251.13, 279.69},{251.13, 379.69}, {251.13, 479.69}, 
 {251.13, 579.69}, {251.13, 679.69}, {251.13, 779.69},{251.13, 879.69}, {251.13, 979.69}, 
 {251.13, 1079.7}, {251.13, 1179.7}, {251.13, 1279.7},{251.13, 1379.7}, {251.13, 1479.7}}
```

And this is the image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, you put a lot of afford in here. I posted the best results I achieved (which should be the most accurate) in the main entry. I do not know the real values as this was not a numerical model. I can also post the picture of model but this may not be reliable, as in the real data from camera, circles are not actual circles, but a kind of "egg shape".

Comment: @Marcin Please post a few images of your "egg shapes" (no pun intended) and let's see if we can come to anything

Comment: Well, I meant that image I have already posted contains "egg shapes". Maybe I just exaggerated the problem, that camera can not see circles as ideal circles. I will post an image of the model with well known centres positions in a few minutes to test your procedure.

Comment: Circles are aligned so it seems, that yours' results are more accurate. I would be grateful if you could analyse the numerical data and post the centres coordinates.

Comment: Thanks. The best algorithm I implemented was slightly better with the numerical data (approximately 0.01 px in 'x' axis and 0.06 px in 'y' axis). On the other hand, yours algorithm seems to be better on real data... Here we comes to another problem -> How to simulate reliable model for this type of tests. I tried Blender to render images of the numerical model (using non-distorted lenses). In Blender I can easily model 3D calibration target with exact distant markers, but I can not anchor this circles with a subpixel precision in rendered image's pixel coordinates.

Comment: Anyway, many Thanks for your help, because you spent a lot of time helping me. I will use some statements, which you posted in my work.

Comment: @Marcin This alg is "tuned" for real data. For matching model data, a least squares fit from the circles boundary will work uch better than mine. There is a lot of bibliography on camera calibration (perhaps you already know this, sorry), generally starting by modeling the camera ... Also, as a comment, circles are usually worse than squares for calibration purpouses, since with straight lines is much easier to detect aberrations. In the past I did some work with circles for doing the QA of a milling machine, ... it was tricky :)

Comment: @Marcin Just taking the mean values for x and y in each circle for your numerical data model you can get very precise values for the center.

Answer (score 3):

"Best" depends on the kind of noise in the input data. The problem is trivial if there is no noise in the source data points: Just pick 3 points and calculate the circle.

If you expect normal distributed, independent translations of each data point, then a least mean squares algorithm should be optimal. The data points should fit the equation:

```
(x - xm)^2 + (y - ym)^2 = r^2
```

where `xm`, `ym`, `r` are unknown, so:

```
x^2 - 2*x*xm + xm^2 + y^2 - 2*y*ym + ym^2 = r^2
```

substitute `c` for `r^2-xm^2-ym^2` and you have an overdetermined system of linear equations:

```
2*x*xm + 2*y*ym = c - x^2 - y^2
```

Any good linear algebra library (e.g. IPP) can solve that for you.

If you expect outliers in the data, I would suggest using a RANSAC-strategy to find the set of non-outlier points, then use the algorithm above to find the exact center for that set.

Comment: Problem is, that the image data comes from camera. I am capturing the image of the kind of calibration target, which contains a set of circular markers. After binarization, edges doesn't have to be evenly distributed around the centre. Furthermore, when observing a circle from an angle, the circle transforms to kind an "egg". Maybe another model (not a circle) should be taken to approximate a centre?

Comment: Least square fitting gave similar results to simple centre of mass algorithm. Seems like its not adequate method.

Comment: If distortions are due to the optics, and they are important, then the first thing you need is to calibrate and undistort (and possibly also rectify) the image. See http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#undistort2 if you use OpenCV. Then you can apply whatever circle matching algorithm you like.

Comment: @Marcin if the camera is tilted you should not match a circle ... Also, if this is a camera calibration procedure, I suggest to state that clearly in the question.

Comment: It is a kind of measuring system calibration procedure, which is made after the standard camera calibration. I posted a sample image in the first entry.

Answer (score 3):

To find circles' centers with subpixel accuracy if the radius of the circle is known (and constant), I use this approach:

1. Take an image with a single circle (refferred to as *marker* below). Its radius should be the same as the radius of the circles you want to find.
2. Detect edges (magnitude of the Sobel gradient, then some threshold to remove low-intensity edges), both in the test image and in the flipped marker image. I do not apply edge thinning at this stage and do not identify exact points on the edge.
3. Cross-correlate edges of the test image with the edges of the flipped marker. You get some peaks where the centers are located.
4. Find peaks' centers with subpixel accuracy. Center of mass or fitting a 2D Gaussian bell may work well.
5. Add shifts which correspond to known position of the center of the circle in the marker.

Otherwise, if points on the circle are known with sufficient accuracy, least mean squares fitting should solve the problem of finding the center (see @nikie's answer).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). It can be used to [detect circles](http://www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg782/lectures/lecture_10/lec782_05_10.pdf).

Comment: Well, I i have read about Hough transform before. I know it is used for detecting circles, but do you know what approximate accuracy in centre determination can be achieved?

Comment: @Marcin It depends on the way you discretize the center/radius space. The good thing is you can take advantage of the neighbouring circles, since they are on one line and equidistant. Just add the parameters of the line where the circle centers are situated to your Hough space.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV 2.4.6.0 has [`findCirclesGrid`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findcirclesgrid) function to find the centers of circles in a grid.